# Apt-get does not find package `git` on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install git on ubuntu 12.04. But when enter the command

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

I get the following message. I have run `sudo apt-get update` already.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  git-el

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to install `git-core` instead

```
sudo apt-get -y install git-core
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting the error :

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git-core is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  git-gui

E: Package 'git-core' has no installation candidate

Comment: Make sure you have main Ubuntu Software packages enabled through Update Manager --> Settings window. If it's there and `sudo apt-get update` doesn't help - try adding git-core ppa to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`: `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu precise main`. And don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` after that.

Comment: I added 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu precise main deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu precise main' but now i am getting 
'W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/deb-src/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/bin.... 404 NotFound
'

Comment: If manual installation doesn't work: remove those lines from sources file and run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`. It should fetch the key as well. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @rooey should i re-add these lines again or not??

Comment: No. You should not. If that doesn't work for you - no need. So the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa` doesn't help? What is the error in this case?

Comment: `You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
   The most current stable version of Git for Ubuntu.
   Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring /tmp/tmpaNiI2Y/secring.gpg' created
...gpg: requesting key E1DF1F24 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpaNiI2Y/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E1DF1F24: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
` but when i try to run 'sudo apt-get install git' i get the response mentioned in the question above.

Comment: Have you done `sudo apt-get update` after adding ppa?

Comment: yes i did that, but no luck. I can install the git on my laptop with out any problem, but i am getting this problem on my desktop.

Comment: I solved this by uncommenting the extras and archive repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.